# JS how to get the substring between two identical string character

Tags: javascript

I know to get a substring between 2 characters we can do something like `myString.substring(myString.lastIndexOf("targetChar") + 1, myString.lastIndexOf("targetChar"));`

But how would I get a substring if the two `targetChar` are the same. For example, if I have something like `const myString = "/theResultSubstring/somethingElse"`, how would I extract `theResultSubstring` in this case?

Comment: There probably is a cool way do do this, but to keep things simple, I would just use const stringArr = myString.split("/"); If you want the first instance, it would be at index 1 in the stringArr.

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot

Comment: Happy to have helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` if there are only two characters in your string:

```js
const myString = "/theResultSubstring/somethingElse";
const subString = myString.substring(myString.indexOf("/") + 1, myString.lastIndexOf("/"));

console.log(subString);
```

Or `split` it:

```js
const myString = "/theResultSubstring/somethingElse";
const subString = myString.split("/")[1];

console.log(subString);
```

Comment: Excellent - glad I could help @X_C95.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `String#match` instead with following regex and *positive* & *negative lookaheads*.

```js
const myString = "/theResultSubstring/somethingElse";

const res = myString.match(/(?!\/)\w+(?=\/)/)[0];

console.log(res);
```